# How do i clear my capybara steps using Page Object Pattern?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara, site-prism

I have the following step definitions with Page Object Pattern gem 'site_prism':

```
class Main < SitePrism::Page
  element :login_link, "a.log-in-link"
  element :login_field, "input[name='userLogin']"
  element :pass_field, "input[name='userPassword']"
  element :enter_button, ".button_pretty"
end

If /I'm log in as "([^"]*)" with password "([^"]*)"$/ do |login, pass|
    @main = Main.new
    @main.login_link.click
    @main.login_field.set login
    @main.pass_field.set pass
    @main.enter_button.click
end
```

It works fine but looks very heavy and unbeautiful. Is there any way to write it like capybara 'within' method? The following isn't work (Error: "can't convert Main into String (TypeError)")

```
within @main do
    login_link.click
    login_field.set login
    pass_field.set pass
    enter_button.click
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't use capybara's `within` functionality with site_prism.

Answer (score 1):

You can hack support for a `with` statement into Ruby:

http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/128781#574402

(I've seen this in VBScript, not sure if any other languages support it out of the box).